# How to use Interface with VCL Classes - Part 2

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

continue with my previous investigation regarding the use of Interface with VCL.

[How to implement identical methods with 2 and more Classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804577/how-to-implement-identical-methods-with-2-and-more-classes)

[How to use Interface with VCL Classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805768/how-to-use-interface-with-vcl-classes)

I would like to have a code example to demonstrate where and how the two work together.
Or what is the classic benefit/usage of the two:

```
ISomething = interface
['{EFE0308B-A85D-4DF3-889C-40FBC8FE84D0}']
...
end;

TSomeThing = class(TSomeVCLObject, ISomething)
...
end;
```

Comment: You need to ask a specific question. This is liable to attract close votes unless you edit it appropriately.

Comment: I think you should state clearly a specific question. This is question 3 and I am not sure any of them are that different.

Comment: Why not to extend the common ancestor instead?

Comment: @user539484, you're right but the original question came up for `TCheckBox` and `TRadioButton` and they have the first common ancestor `TButtonControl` (don't know if also in Delphi 7) and IMHO there's no other way than to modify the VCL source for achieve this (D7 has no class helpers or interception classing). OP is just trying to join two classes where each one went its own way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine you have `TSomeThing` and `TSomeThingElse` classes, but they do not have a common ancestor class.  As-is, you would not be able to pass them to the same function, or call a common method on them.  By adding a shared interface to both classes, you can do both, eg:

```
type
  ISomething = interface 
  ['{EFE0308B-A85D-4DF3-889C-40FBC8FE84D0}'] 
  public
    procedure DoSomething;
  end; 

  TSomeThing = class(TSomeVCLObject, ISomething) 
    ... 
    procedure DoSomething;
  end; 

  TSomeThingElse = class(TSomeOtherVCLObject, ISomething) 
    ... 
    procedure DoSomething;
  end; 

procedure TSomeThing.DoSomething;
begin
  ...
end; 

procedure TSomeThingElse.DoSomething;
begin
  ...
end; 

procedure DoSomething(Intf: ISomething);
begin
  Intf.DoSomething;
end;

procedure Test;
var
  O1: TSomeThing;
  O2: TSomeThingElse;
  Intf: ISomething;
begin
  O1 := TSomeThing.Create(nil);
  O2 := TSomeThingElse.Create(nil);
  ...
  if Supports(O1, ISomething, Intf) then
  begin
    Intf.DoSomething;
    DoSomething(Intf);
  end;
  if Supports(O2, ISomething, Intf) then
  begin
    Intf.DoSomething;
    DoSomething(Intf);
  end;
  ...
  O1.Free;
  O2.Free;
end;
```

Comment: The previous questions were all about implementation inheritance which is of course impossible in Delphi when you are not deriving from a single common ancestor

Comment: finally! the second `if Supports(O1, ISomething, Intf)` should be `O2` no?

Comment: David, in the previous questions I realized that using the Interface is useless. The code you posted is very good, but it is much the some code I use today. I was hoping it could be done otherwise (Interface was suggested), but I just could not realize how and specially when to use it. 10x

Comment: The example Remy gave me now, cleared the mess for me (until next time :wink:).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You can reuse *some* of the implementation if you can use aggregate classes with those interfaces. It's not really inheritance, but it can be very powerful.

Comment: @GolezTrol What is an aggregate class?

Comment: Whoops. I meant to say Delegate instead of Aggregate. Must be because you use TAggregateObject to accomplish this. :)